# Use python to identify elements at screen

Tags: python, machine-learning, frameworks, artificial-intelligence, interface-builder

I want to start a python project thats identify some elements in screen, like a square's size or all elements in screen with a certain color, and i don't even know from where should i start.

For example, all the top points above certain value at the graph.

[image]

Anyone could please give me a north?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to interact with elements inside a browser, look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). If you want to control the desktop itself, look into [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/).

In either case, you can use [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) to identify elements and do template matching.

**Edit: more comments after more details from OP**

If you're just looking to identify the peaks in the graph, you can take a screenshot of the display at regular intervals using Sikuli or [PyScreenshot](https://pypi.org/project/pyscreenshot/) and then use template matching in OpenCV (either directly or using Sikuli) to get the coordinates of the peaks in the screenshot. The horizontal line across the graph might throw off some of the template matching, but you can play around with the various parameters to get the results you want.

[Check out this tutorial for template matching.](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/)

Comment: I think Sikuli is what i'm looking for, but i updated the post trying to be more specific. I'm acception more hints from u frieeends